# Как сделать массовое перемещение файлов на c#?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно, что бы допустим из 50 папок программа в каждую заходила и брала оттуда файл и перемещала в общую папку. Направьте меня пожалуйста.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"c:\text.txt";
    string newPath = @"c:\d\text.txt";
    FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(path);
    if (fileInf.Exists)
    {
        fileInf.MoveTo(newPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: для папок есть DirectoryInfo, у него есть EnumerateFiles и EnumerateDirectories методы. это что касается направить. Другой вопрос - ваши 50 папок в одной папке лежат или где попало? изз папок нужно забрать все файлы или выборочно?

Comment: да, в одной папке и в каждой папке по одному файлу

Comment: а второй вопрос про файлы? и добавьте это в свой вопрос, под ним есть кнопочка править, что бы внести изменения

Comment: т.е. ситуация выглядит так- есть N папок, в каждой папке ровно один файл, и все это богатство нужно собрать в одну папку? у файлов есть что-то общее, тип например или формат имени?

Comment: Именно один формат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если перемещаемые файлы можно объединить общей маской имени, то решение тривиально.

```
var source = new DirectoryInfo("common source dir");
foreach(var file in source.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    file.MoveTo("target path");
}
```

выберет все текстовые файлы из папок размещенных внутри указанной папки source и переместит в указанную папку target. Пути разумеется нужно заменить на нормальные, я просто заглушки вставил.

Comment: Шикарно)) Спасибо огромное! Я давно на c# не работал, только на java и словил дедлайн :|.

Comment: @НикитаСемёнов бывает. Пользуйтесь